# Xcode 7.1 TestFairy SDK 1.5.0, Many Warnings with xxxx.app.dSYM

Tags: xcode7, testfairy

After adding the Test Fairy 1.5.0 SDK and using XCODE 7.0.1, getting many warnings like

```
while processing /Users/jefforthober/Dev/KidMix/KidMixiOS/KidMixCommon/TestFairy/libTestFairy.a(TFImageUtils.o):
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)UIView
while processing /Users/jefforthober/Dev/KidMix/KidMixiOS/KidMixCommon/TestFairy/libTestFairy.a(TFGestureRecognizer.o):
warning: /var/folders/my/m6ynh3bn6tq06h7xr3js0z7r0000gn/C/org.llvm.clang.travis/ModuleCache/1Z8KETWXX2FXQ/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/jefforthober/Dev/KidMix/KidMixiOS/KidMixCommon/TestFairy/libTestFairy.a(TFGestureRecognizer.o):
```

Comment: (I work for TestFairy) we're looking into this. I will post an answer as soon as we have it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Any update on this? @gilm

Comment: This has been fixed in their latest version

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with TestFairy iOS SDK 1.7.4

Just upgrade to the latest version.

http://docs.testfairy.com/iOS_SDK/Integrating_iOS_SDK.html